# Unable to create view for an action unable to retrieve metadata for

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have looked for couple of solutions online such as changing the name of the provider in config file. But the problem rely on when I am creating a new view for the an action I keep getting the following error:

```
There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to
retrieve metadata for' Models.ApplyForJob'.'
```

Model:

```
   public class ApplyForJob
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public string Message {get;set;}
        public DateTime ApplyDate {get;set;}
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual Jobs job {get;set;}
        public virtual ApplicationUser user {get;set;}
    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetJobByUser()
{
    var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var Jobs = db.ApplyForJobs.Where(a => a.UserId == UserId).ToList();
    return View(Jobs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve is to leave the "Data context class" field blank.